# jQuery equivalent of JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to compare the differences between jQuery and JavaScript in a project, but I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite one function because I'm not sure how I'm supposed to reference a jQuery object. I'm concatenating a string to pass as AJAX parameters. Here is the JavaScript:

```
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var values = "";
  var sep = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    if (select.options[i].selected) {
      values += sep + (select.options[i].value);
      sep = ", ";
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

I thought the below might be the jQuery equivalent, passing in $(this), but I can't seem to get it to work.  I wanted it to return empty string if nothing is selected, but it's returning null instead.

```
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var values = "";
  var sep = "";
  $("option:selected", select).each(function(){
    values += sep + ($(this.val()));
    sep = ", ";
  });
  return values;
}
```

I also tried:

```
$(select).each(function(){
  $("option:selected", this).each(function(){
    values += sep + ($(this.val()));
    sep = ", ";
  });
});
```

That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `select` element `$(select).val()` returns the selected value (for single select) or an array or `null` for a multi-select.  I'm assuming from the question that you have a multi-select, so you probably want:

```
var vals = $(select).val();
return vals ? vals.join(', ') : "";
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply can use `.val()` for select with option multiple turned on:

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns null.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: The OP doesn't want `null` to be returned, but an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `each`, `this` is the raw HTML element. You need to wrap in jQuery before invoking jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't read any documentation or [tutorials](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/11/create-callback-functions-for-your.html), did you?

```
$.extend({
    myFunc : function( someArg ) {
        /* …function code… */
    }
});
$.myFunc( args );
```

See: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/11/create-callback-functions-for-your.html

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate your feedback. I never searched for plugins since I'm not building a plugin, so I never came across the tutorial you suggested.

Comment: @Risu That's not only related to plugins, as you can do very different things with functions set up "the jQuery way". I just found that tutorial by searching for "jquery+functions". You are extending jQuery itself with an own function, using that way. You could also extend your own extensions…